# Не удается скачать и установить ни один пакет python командой pip

Tags: pip, wsl2

[image: Скрин неработающей установки пакета python]

Я устанавливал пакеты в WSL2(5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2)(Linux DESKTOP-D5TTG17 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2) (Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) когда использовал роутер для подключения к интернету без проблем, всё работало. После того как подключил кабель к компьютеру напрямую, началась проблема с установкой пакетов посредством команды pip. Для подключения к интернету используется VPN. Помогите мне пожалуйста!

Comment: В Unix подобных системах, лучше использовать **pip3** (python 3 версии)

Answer (score 0):

обновите pip. Если не помогает то заново поставьте питон с галочкой add path. Если после этого не сработает то напишите сюда.